# The History image is broken on the Multi Collider Drop Down as well as the icons for a few other stacks

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stack-exchange-button

Below you can see the History icon and the Philosophy icon broken. There are a few others. Off the top of my head, I know Christianity was one as well.

[image]

I'm viewing in IE8 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced, win7 chrome 30 (although if the content isn't there I don't think this is a client side issue).

Comment: Some of these images are coming from se.com which is currently down (bad build). We are working on resolving the issue.

Comment: Should be OK now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Some of these images are coming from se.com which is currently down (bad build). We are working on resolving the issue.
>
> Should be OK now

- [Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200259/the-history-image-is-broken-on-the-multi-collider-drop-down-as-well-as-the-icons#comment637259_200259)

That did fix the problem!